# DataTables change default sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) with option [`serverSide: true`](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). I see it in the ajax request body that it sends the default ordering option, which is the first column and ASC always.

```
order[0][column]=0&order[0][dir]=asc
```

Is there a way to configure this and change default order setting?

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) page?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg works! I can accept if you answer the question

Comment: thanks, it is a kind of advice that isn't worth an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is below in table settings:

```
    { ....
    serverSide: true,
    order: [ 4, 'desc' ]
    ajax: { ...
```

More details on available options:

https://datatables.net/reference/option

Answer (score 3):

In you DataTable Configuration inside javascript you can specify that with help of,

```
 "order": [[1, "asc"]],
```

I hope this will help you!
Thanks!